# RMS Value of a voltage waveform consisting of a superimposition of 2V DC and a 4 V peak to peak square wave is?

Tags: ac, rms

RMS value should be sqrt(2^2 + (4/sqrt(2))^2) which is equal to sqrt(12), but the answer is sqrt(2^2 + (4/sqrt(2))^2) which is equal to sqrt(8).

Answer (score 1):

Just a hint.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSDq82.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Superimposing 4 V peak-to-peak squarewave on a 2 V DC signal will give a 4 V squarewave.*

Now get the **root** of the **mean** of the **squares**. (This is easy because the duty cycle is 50%.)

- The **square** of the voltage between 0 and T/2 is ...
- The **square** of the voltage between T/2 and T is ...
- The **mean** of those two squares is ...
- The **root** of the mean is ...

Answer (score 0):

A 4 volt p-p square wave has an RMS amplitude of 2 volts therefore: -

$$ \text{RMS of composite DC and AC wave} = \sqrt{2^2 + 2^2} = \sqrt8$$

---

> *RMS value should be sqrt(2^2 + (4/sqrt(2))^2)*

Dividing 4 by \$\sqrt2\$ is something that we would do for a 4 volt peak (not p-p) sinewave. But not for a squarewave because its peak amplitude is the RMS value.